# Linux Shell Scripting recursive exponentation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, recursion, command-line

I am writing a script that takes 2 numbers as an input and uses recursion to power on number to the power of the other, simple exponentiation. However I am new to scripting and cannot figure out where my syntax is errored here.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter number: "
read number
echo "Enter power: "
read power

echo "Powering $number to power of $power!" 

exp () {

    if [ $2 = 1 ]
    then
        return $1
    fi

    return $1 * $(exp $1 $2-1 )

}

result=$(exp $number, $power)

echo "Result: $result"
```

Currently, it kind of freezes, im not sure if I use the parameters correctly (in terms of syntax).

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: This might help: `return` can only return values from 0 to 255.

Comment: @Cyrus That's what I got in bash. In dash, I was able to get 2^30 (but no higher powers of two. Bad idea to use return values in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$(( ))` to force arithmetic evaluation. Then you can do it with return values:

```
number=2 power=7
exp () {
    if [ $2 -eq 1 ]; then return $1; fi
    exp $1 $(($2-1))
    return $(($1 * $?))
}
exp $number $power; result=$?
echo "Result: $result"
```

but it's a bad idea, because shells kind of reserve nonzero return values to communicate failure (e.g. the above solution
will "break" `set -e`).

More idiomatically, you can use stdout:

```
set -e
number=2 power=7
exp () {
    if [ $2 -eq 1 ]; then echo $1; return; fi
    echo $(($1 * $(exp $1 $(($2-1)) ) ))
}
result=$(exp $number $power)
echo "Result: $result"
```

but that's kind of inefficient with all the subshells.
Best to avoid the recursion and simply loop:

```
number=2 power=7
exp () {
    local res=1 i=0;
    while [ $i -lt $2 ]; do res=$((res*$1)); i=$((i+1)); done
    echo $res
}
exp $number $power
```